# How to use textToSpeech in an no activity class?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have a MainActivity class where I want to hear the textToSpeech invoked from a no activity class. The no activity class is called automatically, so I do not call it in order to be able to send the context via a constructor.

This is the no activity class

```
public class SetTiredAction implements Action
{
    private TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    @Override
    public void execute(State state)
    {
        MenuActivity activity = new MenuActivity();
        Log.i("TEIRE", "TIRED");

        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(activity.getContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) 
            {
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) 
                {
                    int ttsLang = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                    Log.i("TTS", "Initialization success.");
                 }
            }
        });
        textToSpeech.speak("Are you tired?", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
        textToSpeech.shutdown();
    }
}
```

In the MenuActivity class I have a methode to get the context, but I get the Error Invocation Target Exception.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: You cannot do that unless you pass valid context to TextToSpeech class. What you're trying to do is totally wrong. You need to either pass the context in a function/class of this no activity class, or use that code in activity where you want to use TextToSpeech.

Comment: ok thank you very much, I will try to include the code where TextToSpeech is used